# Trying to convert generated HTML table to div or ul using jQuery to make it responsive

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, html-table

We have a system that generates a list of products. It places these results all in a yummy(!) table with another nested inside it to wrap around the product image. Each item has an image and the title of the product only, both linked to the product page.

I can't edit any of this generated HTML, but I can edit footer/header etc to add Jquery, and can edit the CSS which is how I've been working around most of my problems.

The only relevant part that I can change in the CMS is how many columns of products are displayed. On a small phone, I want this to be 1, tablet maybe 3, up to 6 for desktops. this is just the width of the tr in the table. If I set this to 1, I figured I could wrap the single td wide trs by floating them next to each other, which I can, yeah.

My problem arises when a product has a long title. If the 4th of 5 products in a row has a longer title, the first product in the next row will be in 5th place, out of order with the first 4 places blank.

Some HTML might help, I guess..

```
<table id="catprods_tbl" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="column_main" align="center" valign="top">
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="column_main">
<a class="links_main" href="/linktoproduct"><img src="/images/thumb.jpg" border="0"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<a class="links_main" href="/linktoproduct">ProductTitle</a><br>£320.00<br><br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

None of this is really editable, but how can I morph it to work how I would like? The double br on the second a is there because normally a short description would be shown between them, but I've hidden that in the CMS as it was messing up the layout on longer descriptions..

Lil 'update (I'll get to grips with site at some point.. )

http://jsfiddle.net/fjnN6/ This explains the problem, when I have a longer title in one of them, the next row starts to the right of it. TIA :)

Comment: It would seem to me that this would be more of a CSS issue. You may want to start by looking at how some of the grid systems, like 960gs, handle tables like this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I got you correctly simple CSS for `td` elements would save time for you:

```
table td {
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This would hide all content that exceeds width property value.
Please provide some screenshots, if that isn't desirable behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Jay Blanchard and Johnny_D - yes, the CSS, >.< I should have included that, sorry. http://jsfiddle.net/fjnN6/ Here's what I mean where the third one has a longer title